# How do I edit text between 2 string delimiters in Python when the string is many lines

Tags: python, xml, replace, elementtree

I am working on converting an XML document to a .ckl document. They are similar file formats, but it is not that simple. I have most of it working, but there is one part I am stuck on.

Before parsing the XML using ElementTree, I have to convert some `&lt;` and `&gt;` to `<` and `>` because the original XML has some errors and needs to be corrected to properly parse. One thing I did not realize was that within some of the groups, I needed to leave the `&lt;` and `&gt;` because the .ckl reader program displays that text as `<` and `>`

Basically, I overcorrect to be able to parse but need to change some back when they are in the `<fixtext>` group.

To do the initial correction, I copy the whole XML file to a variable as one big string and do `data.replace('&lt;', '<')` This works fine and replaces all of the desired instances, but it also corrects the cases where I need to leave the `&lt;`

Right after this, I need to change those few cases in the `<fixtext>` group back before parsing, or else everything is messed up

TL;DR I need to replace `<` and `>` between the delimiters `<fixtest *tags here*>` and `</fixtext>` in a multiline string where the number of lines changes

Any help would be appreciated. If you need more information just let me know and I'd be happy to answer anything

Example of where the original XML is off:

```
<description>&lt;VulnDiscussion&gt;
```

Here, VulnDiscussion should be a new tag

Starting fixtext:

```
<fixtext fixref="F-22407r554595_fix">Configure the policy value for Computer Configuration &gt;&gt;
                Administrative Templates &gt;&gt; Windows Components &gt;&gt; BitLocker Drive Encryption &gt;&gt;
                Operating System Drives "Require additional authentication at startup" to "Enabled" with "Configure TPM
                Startup PIN:" set to "Require startup PIN with TPM" or with "Configure TPM startup key and PIN:" set to
                "Require startup key and PIN with TPM".
</fixtext>
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of the starting XML string?

Comment: Is that enough to go off of? There are multiple instances of fixtext in the document, but that is one example @DarrylG

Comment: @JackMcGowan--possibly enough.  Requested since it's good to provide potential responders with sample text to test their answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Using regular expression**

```
import re
import html # In Python 3.2 a new html module was introduced, which is used for escaping reserved characters from HTML markup

# Example html Text with &lt; and &gt; between and outside tags
html_doc = '''&gt;&gt;&lt;&lt;&lt;&gt;&gt;&lt;&lt;&lt;blahblah<fixtext fixref="F-22407r554595_fix">Configure the policy value for Computer Configuration &gt;&gt;
                Administrative Templates &gt;&gt; Windows Components &gt;&gt; BitLocker Drive Encryption &gt;&gt;
                Operating System Drives "Require additional authentication at startup" to "Enabled" with "Configure TPM
                Startup PIN:" set to "Require startup PIN with TPM" or with "Configure TPM startup key and PIN:" set to
                "Require startup key and PIN with TPM".
</fixtext>&gt;&gt;&lt;&lt;&lt;blahblah'''


# Generate text with substitutions OP wants to reverse later on all the text
html_doc = html_doc.replace('&gt;', '>').replace('&lt;', '<')

# Regex pattern for detecting charcters between tags
p = re.compile(r"(?P<TAG_START><fixtext[^>]*>)(?P<TEXT>.*?)(?P<TAG_END></fixtext>)", flags = re.DOTALL)
indexes = p.groupindex     # groupindex on a compiled regular expression which prints the groups and their orders in the pattern string
                           # i.e. mappingproxy({'TAG_START': 1, 'TEXT': 2, 'TAG_END': 3}
    
# Only escape characters between tags (DOTALL flag for multiline)
corrected = re.sub(pattern, 
                   lambda m: m.group(indexes["TAG_START"]) + html.escape(m.group(indexes["TEXT"])) + m.group(indexes["TAG_END"]), 
                    html_doc) 
print(corrected)
```

**Note corrected has replaced  < and > only between tags**

```
>><<<>><<<blahblah<fixtext fixref="F-22407r554595_fix">Configure the policy value for Computer Configuration &gt;&gt;
                Administrative Templates &gt;&gt; Windows Components &gt;&gt; BitLocker Drive Encryption &gt;&gt;
                Operating System Drives &quot;Require additional authentication at startup&quot; to &quot;Enabled&quot; with &quot;Configure TPM
                Startup PIN:&quot; set to &quot;Require startup PIN with TPM&quot; or with &quot;Configure TPM startup key and PIN:&quot; set to
                &quot;Require startup key and PIN with TPM&quot;.
</fixtext>>><<<blahblah
```